# Sitecore Generallink is not showing Subitems under a Site node

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have used `General Link` field in one of the templates. In my lower environment when Insert Link is clicked I can traverse through all the sites and items under it.

In my higher environment one of the sites and the child items under it are not browsable. The items were moved to higher environment using a package hence not sure where is the issue.

[image]

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Have you checked the security permissions on the site that you can't view?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after package installation. I inspected request in browser and saw:

```
{statusCode: 500, error: {message : "Template is null."}}
```

[image]

Also it was a error on log:

```
ERROR [Item Web API] Template is null.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Template is null.
Source: Sitecore.ItemWebApi
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.GetProperties.GetProperties.Process(GetPropertiesArgs arguments)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult.GetProperties(Item item)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult.CreateItemMock(Item item)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Read.GetResult.Process(ReadArgs arguments)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.ResolveAction.ExecuteReadRequest(RequestArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LaunchRequest.Process(HttpRequestArgs arguments)
```

After investigating the problem, I found that one of the "Home" children item`s template was missing in package. The problem was solved after deploying this missing template.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by different security permissions for your authors in the environment. Have you verified the items are in the content tree? If you login as an admin do the items show up?

I can't recall right now, but it is also possible that dialog drives off of cached/indexed data. Make sure you have cleared the cache and have rebuilt indexes to remove it as a possible source of the problem.